# Function deleteDuplicateElements automata fix

Tags: c

I am trying to solve one of the questions asked in CTS hiring event. Where I have given a code with some error. Without modifying the approach and without using any additional library I have to solve the problem.
It is to remove the duplicate elements and only let the first occurrence of an integer be on the array.
Tell me what i am doing wrong here?

Given error code:

```
#include<stdio.h>
#include<stdlib.h>
typedef struct node {
    int arr[1000];
    int len;
} Numbers;
void* deleteDuplicate (int *arr, int len)
{
    int count=0,p,i,j,k,originalLength=len;
    for(i=0; i<len; i++)
    {
        for(j=i+1; j<len; j++)
        {
            if(arr[j]==arr[i])
            {
                arr[k]=arr[k+1];
            }
            len=len-1;
            count=count+1;
            j=i;
        }
    }

    int  newLength = originalLength-count;
    Numbers *numbers = malloc(sizeof(*numbers));
    for(i=0; i<newLength; i++)
        numbers->arr[i]=arr[i];
    numbers->len = newLength;
    return numbers;
}

int main() {
    int arr[]={2,3,2,2,5,6,6,7};
    Numbers *n = deleteDuplicate(arr,8);
    for(int i=0;i<n->len;i++){
        printf("%d ",arr[i]);
    }
}
```

My solution:

```
#include<stdio.h>
#include<stdlib.h>
typedef struct node {
    int arr[1000];
    int len;
} Numbers;
void* deleteDuplicate (int *arr, int len)
{
    int count=0,p,i,j,k,originalLength=len;
    for(i=0; i<len; i++)
    {
        for(j=i+1; j<len; j++)
        {
            if(arr[j]==arr[i])
            {
                for(k=j;k<len-1;k++)
                arr[k]=arr[k+1];
            
            len=len-1;
            count=count+1;
            j=i;
            }
        }
    }

    int  newLength = originalLength-count;
    Numbers *numbers = malloc(sizeof(*numbers));
    for(i=0; i<newLength; i++)
        numbers->arr[i]=arr[i];
    numbers->len = newLength;
    return numbers;
}

int main() {
    int arr[]={2,3,2,2,5,6,6,7};
    Numbers *n = deleteDuplicate(arr,8);
    for(int i=0;i<n->len;i++){
        printf("%d ",arr[i]);
    }
}
```

My solution gives output for some cases only.

Comment: Where is the test case where your code is not working properly ?

Comment: I am sorry about the case its been hidden from me. And am trying to solve it for like 6 hours. No idea where i am doing wrong.

Comment: It's hard to fix it, without having the test case, try playing around with the input array until you find the bad case, then use the debugger to fix it.

Comment: Your code works for me...

Comment: Thank you for accepting the (forgotten) answer below. Revisited the answer with a possible alternative way of doing this (without using `malloc()`... `:-)`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your problem may be in this line from `main()`

```
printf("%d ",arr[i]);
```

You are printing from the initial array, not the returned struct's array that you've filled...

```
printf( "%d ", n->arr[i] );
```

Another way to view this is that the function must return an allocated structure.
If you do that first (NB: `calloc()` to ensure it is zero'd to begin), then don't muck with shifting elements to shrink-out duplicates. Simply test against those that have already been seen once...

```
typedef struct node {
    int arr[1000];
    int len;
} Numbers;

Numbers *deleteDuplicates( int *arr, int len ) {
    Numbers *pRet = (Numbers *)calloc( 1, sizeof *pRet );
    if( pRet == NULL ) // ALWAYS test return values.
        exit( -1 );

    pRet->arr[ pRet->len++ ] = arr[0]; // first one is free
    for( int i = 1; i < len; i++ ) {
        for( int j = 0; j < pRet->len; j++ )
            if( arr[i] == pRet->arr[j] ) // seen before?
                break;
        if( j == pRet->len ) // Hmm... Not seen before!
            pRet->arr[ pRet->len++ ] = arr[i];
    }

    return pRet;
}

int main( void ) {
    int arr[] = { 2, 3, 2, 2, 5, 6, 6, 7 };

    Numbers *n = deleteDuplicates( arr, 8 );
    if( n == NULL )
        exit( -1 );

    for( int i = 0; i < n->len; i++ )
        printf( "%d ", n->arr[i] );
    putchar( '\n' );

    free( n ); // don't forget!

    return 0;
}
```

Output

```
2 3 5 6 7
```

EDIT: Alternative version that does not require 2nd (possibly huge) parallel array. This 'finds' a `sentinel value` that does NOT appear in the array, then uses that to *clobber* duplicate values further into the array. It then *compacts* the (now unique) values in the original array. A few adjustments made to function signatures in keeping with the struct definition (also altered), and a few "debug" print statements just for fun.

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

typedef struct { // use simpler typedef. Not a "node"
    int *arr; // more flexible than fixed size
    size_t len; // use size_t for size, not signed int
} Numbers_t; // conventional name style with "_t"

// Find a value that does NOT appear in the data
int findSentinel( int a[], size_t sz ) {
    int val;

    // deliberate collision starting with 2 to prove function
    // more sensible to start with INT_MIN, or maybe INT_MAX (from limits.h)
    for( val = 2; val < 1000 * 1000; val++ ) {
        printf( "Sentinel %d ? ", val ); // debugging

        for( size_t i = 0; i < sz && a[i] != val; i++ )
            ; // searching

        // Good? return, else keep searching
        if( i == sz ) { puts( "YES!" ); return val; }
        puts( "Nope..." );
    }
    // may not be able to use this technique
    fprintf( stderr, "Cannot find a sentinel value\n" );
    exit( EXIT_FAILURE );
    return -1; // quiet compiler warning
}

// Notice changed function signature using struct declaration
Numbers_t *deleteDuplicates( Numbers_t *n ) {
    size_t i, j;

    int sntnl = findSentinel( n->arr, n->len );
    printf( "Sentinel value (%d)\n", sntnl );

    // iterative search and replace of 2nd, 3rd... instances of array values
    for( i = 0; i < n->len; i++ ) {
        int got = n->arr[i];

        if( got == sntnl ) continue; // skip over these

        for( j = i+1; j < n->len; j++ )
            if( n->arr[j] == got ) { // seen before?
                printf( "%d dupe @ pos %d\n", got, j+1 ); // debug
                n->arr[j] = sntnl; // clobber duplicate
            }
    }
    // compact the array to unique values
    for( i = j = 0; i < n->len; i++ )
        if( n->arr[i] != sntnl )
            n->arr[j++] = n->arr[i];

    n->len = j; // array may have fewer elements now
    return n;
}

// service function
void printArr( Numbers_t *n ) {
    for( size_t i = 0; i < n->len; i++ )
        printf( "%d ", n->arr[i] );
    putchar( '\n' );
}

int main() {
    int arr[] = { 2, 3, 2, 2, 5, 6, 6, 7 };

    // fill provided struct with sample data
    Numbers_t n = { arr, sizeof arr/sizeof arr[0] };

    printArr( &n );

    deleteDuplicates( &n );

    printArr( &n );

    return 0;
}
```

Output

```
2 3 2 2 5 6 6 7
Sentinel 2 ? Nope...
Sentinel 3 ? Nope...
Sentinel 4 ? YES!
Sentinel value (4)
2 dupe @ pos 3
2 dupe @ pos 4
6 dupe @ pos 7
2 3 5 6 7
```

EDIT 2: Finally 'twigged' that the value in a[0] is unique when the scanning is just getting started. That value can act as what I'd called the "sentinel value"... This eliminates the need to loop around *guessing* what might work...

`findSentinel()` is gone, and 3 lines changed in this function:

```
// Notice changed function signature using struct declaration
void deleteDuplicates( Numbers_t *n ) {
    size_t i, j;

    int sntnl = n->arr[0];
    printf( "Sentinel value (%d)\n", sntnl );

    // iterative search and replace of 2nd, 3rd... instances of array values
    for( i = 1; i < n->len; i++ ) {
        int got = n->arr[i];

        if( got == sntnl ) continue; // skip over these

        for( j = i+1; j < n->len; j++ )
            if( n->arr[j] == got ) { // seen before?
                printf( "%d dupe @ pos %d\n", got, j+1 ); // debug
                n->arr[j] = sntnl; // clobber duplicate
            }
    }
    // compact the array to unique values
    for( i = j = 1; i < n->len; i++ )
        if( n->arr[i] != sntnl )
            n->arr[j++] = n->arr[i];

    n->len = j; // array may have fewer elements now
}
```